# Python Selenium instagram bot clicking same picture

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, ui-automation, webautomation

I am trying to type `#likeforfollow` in search bar, which was successful. Then I tried to use a for loop to click on every picture but it just clicks on same picture every time. I want to click every picture here is my code:

```
for pic in driver.find_elements_by_class_name('eLAPa'):
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('''//*[@id="react-root"]/section/main/article/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div[3]/a/div''').click()
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("""/html/body/div[3]/div/button""").click()
```

Comment: This is very broad. Perhaps give us the HTML you are scanning, otherwise we can not know how to help you.

Comment: @PL200 if you search #likeforfollow  in the search bar on Instagram I'm trying to click every picture on that page.

Comment: you are looping over `pic`, but then inside that loop search for static xpath. Makes no sense. (also terrible xpath, makes debugging nearly impossible)

Comment: On what website, @Noah? StackOverflow? Now, I'm guessing the answer is 'Instagram', but you need to specify that sort of stuff in your question.

Answer (score 0):

As an example, check this code:

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome()

browser.get('https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/')
wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 5)
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//input[@name="username"]'))).send_keys('USERNAME')
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@type="password"]').send_keys('PASSWORD')
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//button[contains(text(), "Log in")]').click()

browser.get('https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/likeforfollow/')
for i in range(10):
    browser.execute_script('window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);')
    time.sleep(1)

pics = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,     '//a[contains(@href, "tagged=likeforfollow")]')))
links = [pic.get_attribute("href") for pic in pics]
for link in links:
    browser.get(link)
    wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//button[contains(@class, "coreSpriteHeartOpen")]'))).click()

browser.close()
```

**Imports:**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time
```

You are welcome!